# On button click of one open page I want another already opened page in browser to come to focus

Tags: javascript

On button click of one open page i want other already opened page in browser to come to focus - JavaScript

I have the above requirement, i have tried win.focus but it is not working.

basically my requirement is - i have 'www.google.com' page opened in one tab and on other tab i have my custom page 'www.example.com' and i have a button event in that page. So if i click the button i want to completely move from 'www.example.com' page and land on 'www.google.com' (with out opening any new windows or tabs)

Comment: What have you tried? (share code)

Comment: Win.focus after storing the required url in win....
But it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize a variable with your opened `window`:

```
var newWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

And then you need to have an `onclick` event for the tag we are talking about:

```
<input type="button" onclick="newWindow.focus()">
```

Make sure `newWindow` is available, try it with a global first and when that works, refactor this to be more elegant, without using globals.